# iOS certificates and provisioning profiles relation

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning, flash-builder

Yes, yes, another one of this kind. I know all the general gist, what's for what, how to generate, etc.

Just have something that bugs me. Basically, what is the relation of certificate and provisioning profile? I've failed to find a proper answer to this. The reason I'm asking is that I always thought that because when we create provisioning profile, we match it with development (for development provisioning) or distribution (for adhoc and appstore provisioning) certificate, it would mean that provisioning profiles are tied to certificates.

But recently, working with Flash Builder, when compiling my Flex app, I've noticed that it's either not the case, or there is something I don't understand going on inbetween. Basically, I've noticed that I can pick my development certificate and use adhoc provisioning and the application compiles fine and runs fine. I always thought I cannot do that, as I can only use adhoc provisioning with distribution certificate. How is that possible, if adhoc provisioning was tied to distribution certificate? I don't think it's really FB related, since in the end I install the app via iTunes and on iOS device, and it still works, so it must be Apple thing.

It would actually seem that as long as I don't distribute for AppStore, I can pick whatever combination of certificate/provisioning files I want, and the application will still compile and run fine on devices, as long as the appid and udids are fine. Obviously adhoc and appstore provisioning have the process attachment disabled (debugging) and target different service servers for push etc., but other than, it's just fine. Why then there's this visible match in iOS Provisioning portal, that certain profiles belong to a certificate?

Does that mean that certificates are just way of separating concerns (developers vs company/distributor). In iOS Provisioning Portal, only Team Agents can create distribution certificates and adhoc profiles, but once generated, it would seem that Agent can handle adhoc profile to developer and he can sign it using his development certificate.

I'm having problems with properly tying everything and still make sense out of it. Interwebs, help!

Comment: Could it be in any way related to the fact that both my development and distribution certificates were created using the same private key? It would be still weird as then the private key would be the main factor, not the certificate...

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to answer you question in a few words as it is a very loaded question that navigates into several aspects of code signing (and looks like you may have had caching issues also) But your question boils down to two issues -

1. What role do certificates/profiles/keys play during the creation of an IPA file?
2. How does the device validate the IPA when the IPA is executed?

Lets assume you are using Xcode and have an Enterprise Apple Developer Account and are starting from scratch  with the "keychain" utility to create a CSR. While performing the CSR creation, two keys (a private key and a public key) are created that are actually added to the keychain of your machine. The CSR that is generated and saved on your local machine has all the information you provided (including your public key) in an encrypted form - it is encrypted using your private key

{ your name + your email + your public key} => encrypt using your private key => CSR

Now when you send the encoded CSR and a copy of your unencrypted version of you public key to Apple, they can be sure of your identity and and be sure that the CSR was sent by you - since only you have the private key to encode the information which they can successfully decode using your public key only.

If the CSR validation succeeds, Apple takes your CSR and creates a developer certificate and allows you to download it. This basically is a "notarized" certificate that is signed by Apple certifying you as a verified developer. Think of it as a file signed using apple's private key that you can decode using apple's public key. At this point your identity and apples identity have been authenticated.

Next when you create a provisioning profile, you have to choose the ingredients that it needs - udids, dev certs etc

(UDIDS + Dev Certificates + App Identifier + Entitlements) => Provisioning profile

Next you download this profile add it to Xcode (using the Xcode organizer) Wheew we are done!

Now that you have all the ingredients (keys, profiles, certificates) for creating a signed IPA file, XCode steps in and does a verification/background check. The way Xcode verifies this is by inspecting each of the individual developer certificates that is embedded in the chosen mobile provisioning file. It checks to see if you have the private/public keys in your keychain for each of the embedded developer certificates (inside the provisioning profile). It then allows you to perform the signing process using any of the certificates that have matching keys - i.e dev certificates that has matching keys in your keychain.. You now have a signed IPA. Hope that explain hows things are tied together during the IPA creation process. How these play together when a signed IPA executes is part two of the story :)